# file as input for script

Tags: bash, file, input

I have a simple script (timeconvert.sh) that converts seconds into hh:mm:ss format and writes it to a file *timeremain.out*:

```
#!/bin/bash
#convert sec to h:m:s
secs=${1:?}

h=$(( secs / 3600 ))
m=$(( ( secs / 60 ) % 60 ))
s=$(( secs % 60 ))

printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n" $h $m $s > timeremain.out
```

I am trying to get it to read a file *secremain.out* as the input for the script but none of the following work:

```
cat secremain.out | ./timeconvert.sh
./timeconvert.sh < secremain.out
```

Can anyone suggest the proper syntax to use or an edit to the script to read the file directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script reads the seconds from `$1` so you can either pass them in on the command line:

```
secs=$(cat secremain.out)
./timeconvert.sh $secs

# or

./timeconvert.sh $(cat secremain.out)
```

Or you can change your script to read from stdin:

```
#!/bin/bash
#convert sec to h:m:s
read secs
```

If you do the latter then it can read from the file the way you wrote:

```
cat secremain.out | ./timeconvert.sh
./timeconvert.sh < secremain.out
```

Comment: Note: `$(<file)` is a bash shortcut for `$(cat file)`

Answer (score 0):

### With this script

:
you can both use `STDIN` or an argument, the script detect itself the context :

```
#!/bin/bash
#convert sec to h:m:s

if [[ -t 0 ]]; then
    secs=${1:?}
else
    read secs
fi

h=$(( secs / 3600 ))
m=$(( ( secs / 60 ) % 60 ))
s=$(( secs % 60 ))

printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n" $h $m $s
```

### Usage Examples

```
./script.sh 120
```

or

```
echo 120 | ./script.sh
```